# Android REORDER_TO_FRONT with duplicit Activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, flags

is there any possibility how to recall(reorder to front) Activity from backstack when one of the same type (class) is at the top?

If there is..HOW? :-D

example:

1. I start **ActivityA** with 
   `new Intent(ActivityH.this, ActivityA.class);`
2. Then I start **ActivityB** with 
   `new Intent(ActivityH.this, ActivityB.class);`
3. Then **ActivityC** with 
   `new Intent(ActivityH.this, ActivityC.class);`
4. Then **ActivityD** with 
   `new Intent(ActivityF.this, ActivityD.class);`
5. And then again **ActivityC** with 
   `new Intent(ActivityF.this, ActivityC.class);`

Now I want to recall(move to the top of the stack) **3. ActivityC**
And I dont want to finish **4.** and **5.**

So i ended like this: A -> B -> C(1) -> D -> C(2)

And I need to do something like this: A -> B -> D -> C(2) -> C(1)

 
When I want A/B/D everything works fine with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` but C is not working...

Thx to all